# Из программы на java авторизоваться на стороннем сайте и выгрузить html-код страницы

Tags: http-redirect, java

Всем привет! Необходимо из программы на java авторизоваться на стороннем сайте и выгрузить html-код страницы, используя  httpClient. Нижеприведенный код выводит в результате ошибку:

> org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException:
> Object moved (код состояния 302 -
> страница временна доступна по другому
> адресу, указанному в поле Location).

Вход работает, поскольку, если я задаю неверный логин и пароль, то получаю сообщение о том что пароль неверный. Каким образом мне осуществить перенаправление на другую страницу? Гугл говорит мне, что нужно использовать httpclient.setRedirectStrategy, разбираюсь, пока результата нет

Текст программы:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {

            HttpPost("http://.../login.asp");

            List < NameValuePair > nvps = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "myname"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpass", "mypass"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            ResponseHandler < String > responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println(responseBody);

            finally {
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                System.out.println("Это конец.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема решилась посредством использования LaxRedirectStrategy
Почитать можно здесь http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-redirect-on-http-post